# Conversion from xts to zooreg time series removes date values

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo

I hope you are having a nice day!

First, here's the dput of my data:

```
StreamsTempAveragextsMonthly <- structure(c(16.44, 15.7230769230769, 16.4484358974359, 16.2202307692308, 
15.6025, 16.4114423076923, 16.7097115384615, 16.32125, 16.7625, 
16.8855769230769, 17.864358974359, 18.4282692307692, 17.5625, 
16.9068269230769, 17.1636730769231, 16.8279230769231, 17.09125, 
17.8747916666667, 17.2025, 16.9225, 17, 17.75, 17.85, 17.3663461538462, 
17.4355769230769, 16.8797115384615, 17.0658717948718, 17.2979230769231, 
17.2128205128205, 17.78225, 17.48, 16.9457051282051, 18.535, 
18.5871634615385, 17.7346153846154, 18.214188034188, 16.7875, 
16.6706196581197, 17.103125, 17.3691346153846, 17.8264423076923, 
16.4920192307692, 16.8905128205128, 16.9484615384615, 17.350641025641, 
17.9035096153846, 18.1136363636364, 18.0958, 18.125, 17.3089871794872, 
17.3978205128205, 17.8078985507246, 17.6580384615385, 17.7281643356643, 
17.3222222222222, 17.6125555555556, 18.4708333333333, 18.9261363636364, 
18.3610714285714, 18.2842857142857, 17.5, 18.9776818181818, 18.2313068181818, 
18.5352272727273, 18.2314393939394, 16.8462121212121, 17.5330452568202, 
16.5851136363636, 18.3415151515152, 19.0620454545455, 17.5744047619048, 
16.7176308539945, 16.6407407407407, 16.7227272727273, 16.4184848484848, 
17.5290598290598, 17.1817965367965, 16.4547619047619, 15.9484848484848, 
15.6835902503294, 16.0388865398168, 17.0166666666667, 17.5905555555556, 
16.4290088383838, 16.2997452016069, 16.1557023172906, 16.7221212121212, 
16.857196969697, 17.3215277777778, 16.5125, 16.0752525252525, 
15.5828743589744, 16.6117845117845, 17.9668930686172, 17.5651666666667, 
16.3064442224442, 16.2763888888889, 17.650505050505, 16.8803872053872, 
17.3298611111111, 17.3772443181818, 17.0242424242424, 16.8111111111111, 
16.8055555555556, 17.232601010101, 17.8261363636364, 17.3753787878788, 
16.5777272727273, 15.8893939393939, 16.9522435897436, 16.5363636363636, 
16.6034090909091, 17.2667929292929, 18.0511363636364, 17.5534090909091, 
16.4551136363636, 17.23125, 17.5136363636364, 17.8482954545455, 
16.9869318181818, 16.4244318181818, 17.125, 16.8022727272727, 
17.4343006993007, 17.2990909090909, 17.1961538461538, 17.009375, 
16.9174747474747, 17.2710227272727, 17.6715909090909, 17.4818181818182, 
15.9962121212121, 16.5631818181818, 16.6078349282297, 17.1787878787879, 
17.0653409090909, 17.4431818181818, 17.4880681818182, 15.0918803418803, 
16.7741339869281, 17.4332792207792, 17.7990981240981, 18.0886363636364, 
16.8297619047619, 16.6851973684211, 17.2556818181818, 17.0295454545455, 
16.8240909090909, 16.7538770053476, 16.2579545454545, 15.9655757575758, 
17.1280753968254, 17.7519191919192, 17.4414335664336, 17.4557954545455, 
16.1622115384615, 16.8327651515152, 16.9667613636364, 16.672798573975, 
16.9659090909091, 17.0818181818182, 17.1822027972028, 17.8164884135472, 
17.4545454545455, 16.7771212121212, 17.8238636363636, 17.7005244755245, 
16.7160984848485, 16.341754756871, 16.6440025252525, 16.9829545454545, 
16.6630555555556, 19.1123467230444, 19.3261363636364, 17.7603021978022, 
18.8059107142857, 18.2065559440559, 18.25, 16.965, 18.0582115800866, 
17.2105637254902, 18.6762012987013, 18.4136363636364, 18.2600378787879, 
18.0003496503497, 17.9288825757576, 17.959375, 18.5164772727273, 
18.4772727272727, 18.2170454545455, 18.90625, 16.7813725490196, 
17.2660256410256, 17.0635542929293, 17.2422902097902, 17.1887820512821, 
16.1727941176471, 16.0860294117647, 18.3868181818182, 18.0298076923077, 
18.7031536293164, 18.3659090909091, 18.625, 16.7256818181818, 
17.2232600732601, 18.3319639192886, 17.9238636363636, 17.9799422799423, 
16.5837121212121, 16.100952540107, 16.9387019230769, 17.3568181818182, 
17.1753146853147, 17.1159090909091, 18.1145833333333, 16.8415170940171, 
16.9133597285068, 17.6888034188034, 17.1259793447293, 17.384655448718, 
16.7841346153846, 16.2973468660969, 16.1201495726496, 17.5849893162393, 
18.2456018518519, 18.0254807692308, 17.4643233618234, 17.1731532356532, 
17.5413283475783, 17.7156695156695, 17.5869255189255, 17.6197802197802, 
17.1997996794872, 17.6756588319088, 18.048433048433, 18.5746082621083, 
19.1991987179487, 18.6432081807082, 16.8430288461538, 17.4325367647059, 
17.314707977208, 17.5010576923077, 17.9123219373219, 17.4, 17.5033333333333, 
17.8433333333333, 18.9353846153846, 18.6049679487179, 17.1923076923077, 
17.4415196078431, 17.6505057932264, 17.2357352941176, 17.9955326484661, 
17.5959523809524, 17.5952941176471, 16.9622171945701, 18.2641666666667, 
17.3842124183007, 18.8371301247772, 18.2442091503268, 17.8693572984749, 
17.4261783559578, 17.8408721670486, 18.0430294117647, 17.5234615384615, 
18.7757894736842, 18.0545833333333, 18.3861029411765, 17.2286764705882, 
19.1830882352941, 18.9825490196078, 19.399375, 18.8928921568627, 
17.379375, 17.8381315789474, 18.9048611111111, 18.32625, 18.5, 
17.1804924242424, 17.165, 19.0856617647059, 18.6882066993464, 
18.949358974359, 18.2374264705882, 17.9036554621849, 17.7655882352941, 
18.0464795008913, 19.0757010582011, 18.0125, 17.0503365384615, 
17.4858707264957, 18.0303062678063, 19.0284455128205, 18.0894444444444, 
18.4038461538462), .Dim = c(295L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    "AverageTemp"), index = structure(c(741398400, 742003200, 
746668800, 749347200, 751766400, 754185600, 757209600, 759628800, 
762048000, 765072000, 767491200, 770256000, 772243200, 775353600, 
778118400, 780710400, 783216000, 785635200, 788054400, 791424000, 
793238400, 796521600, 798940800, 801360000, 803865600, 807148800, 
809740800, 812246400, 814406400, 817603200, 819244800, 823046400, 
824860800, 827884800, 830131200, 833328000, 835315200, 838771200, 
841190400, 843609600, 846633600, 849052800, 851904000, 854496000, 
857088000, 859420800, 861321600, 864864000, 867110400, 870220800, 
872640000, 875491200, 878083200, 880502400, 883353600, 885945600, 
888364800, 890784000, 893808000, 895190400, 900115200, 904521600, 
907027200, 909532800, 911952000, 913161600, 916790400, 919555200, 
921715200, 925257600, 928108800, 930700800, 933292800, 935712000, 
938131200, 941155200, 942969600, 945734400, 949017600, 951436800, 
953856000, 956016000, 958694400, 962064000, 964483200, 966988800, 
970185600, 972604800, 974937600, 977443200, 980208000, 982800000, 
985910400, 987984000, 991267200, 993772800, 994723200, 999216000, 
1001548800, 1004054400, 1006473600, 1008892800, 1012435200, 1014854400, 
1017446400, 1019260800, 1022803200, 1025308800, 1027728000, 1030147200, 
1032566400, 1034985600, 1038614400, 1039824000, 1043452800, 1045872000, 
1048291200, 1050624000, 1053129600, 1056758400, 1059177600, 1060387200, 
1064016000, 1067558400, 1070064000, 1071273600, 1074902400, 1077580800, 
1079740800, 1083283200, 1084579200, 1087948800, 1091232000, 1093651200, 
1096070400, 1098489600, 1100908800, 1103328000, 1106352000, 1108771200, 
1111190400, 1114819200, 1116028800, 1117843200, 1122076800, 1124496000, 
1128038400, 1130544000, 1133222400, 1135209600, 1138665600, 1140825600, 
1143244800, 1145664000, 1148083200, 1151107200, 1154131200, 1156550400, 
1158969600, 1161388800, 1163808000, 1166227200, 1169251200, 1171670400, 
1175299200, 1177718400, 1180051200, 1183161600, 1185580800, 1.188e+09, 
1190419200, 1191628800, 1196294400, 1197676800, 1200614400, 1203120000, 
1206748800, 1209168000, 1210377600, 1214006400, 1216339200, 1220054400, 
1222473600, 1224892800, 1227312000, 1229731200, 1232755200, 1235174400, 
1237507200, 1240012800, 1242432000, 1248480000, 1250553600, 1253318400, 
1256947200, 1259280000, 1260576000, 1262995200, 1266710400, 1269043200, 
1272585600, 1275091200, 1275350400, 1280534400, 1282953600, 1285372800, 
1287792000, 1290211200, 1292630400, 1295568000, 1298073600, 1299283200, 
1304035200, 1306454400, 1307664000, 1311984000, 1314316800, 1316822400, 
1319241600, 1322611200, 1324080000, 1327104000, 1330473600, 1333152000, 
1335571200, 1338249600, 1340323200, 1342828800, 1346371200, 1348790400, 
1351209600, 1353628800, 1356134400, 1359158400, 1360368000, 1363910400, 
1366416000, 1369699200, 1375228800, 1377648000, 1379635200, 1382486400, 
1384992000, 1386892800, 1391126400, 1393545600, 1395360000, 1398297600, 
1401235200, 1406246400, 1408579200, 1412035200, 1414713600, 1417046400, 
1418428800, 1421712000, 1424217600, 1426723200, 1430352000, 1432944000, 
1435276800, 1438214400, 1440979200, 1443398400, 1444867200, 1447372800, 
1449619200, 1453334400, 1456704000, 1459382400, 1461715200, 1463011200, 
1466726400, 1469059200, 1472601600, 1475020800, 1477440000, 1479168000, 
1481155200, 1484179200, 1487721600, 1489968000, 1491436800, 1495065600, 
1498780800, 1501027200, 1503446400, 1508544000, 1510963200, 1513296000, 
1516233600, 1519171200, 1520812800, 1523318400, 1525219200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC", class = c("xts", 
"zoo"))
```

It has this structure:

```
 An ‘xts’ object on 1993-06-30/2018-05-02 containing:
  Data: num [1:295, 1] 16.4 15.7 16.4 16.2 15.6 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr "AverageTemp"
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL
```

Notice how the last date is 2018-05-02? Now, the problem is when I convert my xts object into a zooreg object. I used this code:

```
 StreamsTempzooreg <- zooreg(StreamsTempAveragextsMonthly, start = c(1993,6), end = c(2018,5), frequency = 12)
```

It has this structure:

```
‘zooreg’ series from Jun 1993 to Dec 2017
  Data: num [1:295, 1] 16.4 15.7 16.4 16.2 15.6 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:295] "1993-06-30" "1993-07-07" "1993-08-30" "1993-09-30" ...
  ..$ : chr "AverageTemp"
  Index:  'yearmon' num [1:295] Jun 1993 Jul 1993 Aug 1993 Sep 1993 ...
  Frequency: 12
```

It changes the last date to December 2017. Why is this happening? How can I fix it so that the original end date is May 2018?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `as.zooreg`, not `zooreg`.  `zooreg` is used to construct a zooreg object from its data and index whereas `as.zooreg` is used to convert other objects to zooreg class.  The first argument of `zooreg` specifies the data portion and the other arguments specify the index portion.  The first argument of `zooreg` should be a numeric vector or matrix but since an xts object was given instead it took the data portion of it ignoring the time index.

`as.zooreg` can be used to convert from xts class to zooreg class.  The first line below does the converstion keeping the Date class index and then the next line converts the index to year/month using the `yearmon` class.

```
zr <- as.zooreg(StreamsTempAveragextsMonthly)
zr <- aggregate(zr, as.yearmon, c) ##
range(index(zr))
## [1] "Jun 1993" "May 2018"
```

The line marked ## could alternatley be written:

```
index(zr) <- as.yearmon(index(zr))
```